# How to change the index/offset of a list (Python)?

Tags: python

In C I can do something like:

```
return byte_99DC2C[byte_C06740[dword_C06738]++];
```

In Lua I can do something like:

```
memory.readbyte(0x83084+memory.readbyte(0x62e10+(memory.readbyte(0x62e18)+1)));
```

How can I do this in Python and with a list (since I can't do operations on RAM)?

I tried something like this in Python, but it is wrong:

```
rn_table = [0x63, 0x06, 0xF0, 0x23, 0xF8, 0xE5, 0xA8, 0x01, 0xC1, 0xAE, 0x7F, 0x48,
0x7B, 0xB1, 0xDC, 0x09, 0x22, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0xEE, 0x9D, 0x58, 0xD5, 0x55, 0x24, 0x39, 0x7A, 0xDF,
0x8E, 0x54, 0x6C, 0x1B, 0xC0, 0x0B, 0xD0, 0x43, 0xD8, 0x9A, 0x47, 0x5D, 0x21, 0x02, 0x17, 0x4B,
0xDB, 0x11, 0xAF, 0x70, 0xCD, 0x4D, 0x34, 0x49, 0x72, 0x91, 0x2D, 0x62, 0x97, 0x59, 0x45, 0xF7,
0x6E, 0x46, 0xAA, 0x0A, 0xA3, 0xC8, 0x31, 0x92, 0x38, 0xFA, 0xD4, 0xE6, 0xCB, 0xF3, 0xDE, 0x6B,
0xBB, 0xF1, 0x1C, 0x3C, 0xD6, 0xAD, 0xB2, 0xA9, 0xDD, 0x57, 0x42, 0x95, 0x0C, 0x79, 0x25, 0x1F,
0xBC, 0xE7, 0xAC, 0x5B, 0x83, 0x28, 0x76, 0xF2, 0x18, 0xDA, 0x87, 0xA1, 0x61, 0x6F, 0xBE, 0x5A,
0x5E, 0x51, 0xEF, 0xB0, 0xC9, 0x15, 0x74, 0x89, 0xBD, 0xD1, 0xA2, 0x75, 0xD7, 0x99, 0x85, 0x4C,
0x4F, 0xD2, 0xBF, 0x4A, 0x20, 0x08, 0x56, 0xA0, 0x50, 0x3A, 0x67, 0x26, 0x41, 0x33, 0xB7, 0xBA,
0xFB, 0x30, 0xCF, 0x7C, 0x84, 0x2C, 0x32, 0xE9, 0x1D, 0x16, 0x82, 0x78, 0xA4, 0x80, 0x65, 0x5F,
0x0E, 0x27, 0xB9, 0x19, 0xC3, 0xA7, 0xB6, 0x00, 0x3B, 0xFC, 0x88, 0xE1, 0xC6, 0x93, 0xFE, 0x8B,
0xD9, 0xB8, 0x13, 0x69, 0x2F, 0x64, 0x12, 0x37, 0xFD, 0x77, 0xE2, 0xB5, 0x04, 0xE0, 0x1A, 0x8C,
0x8F, 0xB4, 0xCC, 0xF9, 0x60, 0xEB, 0x29, 0xE3, 0x90, 0xA5, 0x68, 0x3D, 0x81, 0x73, 0x3F, 0xAB,
0x7E, 0xB3, 0x0F, 0xCE, 0xC4, 0x35, 0x94, 0x96, 0x86, 0x71, 0xD3, 0x2A, 0xE4, 0x9F, 0x9C, 0xEC,
0x4E, 0x14, 0xF5, 0xEA, 0x40, 0xA6, 0xF6, 0x03, 0x98, 0xC5, 0x07, 0xF4, 0x2B, 0xC2, 0x3E, 0xE8,
0x9B, 0x36, 0x53, 0x2E, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0x52, 0x10, 0x66, 0x1E, 0xED, 0x8A, 0x44, 0x9E, 0x05, 0xFF,
0x5C, 0xC7, 0x6A, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x12, 0x19, 0x21, 0x27, 0x2D, 0x35, 0x3D, 0x49, 0x51, 0x5A,
0x62, 0x69, 0x72, 0x7A, 0x83, 0x8B, 0x94, 0x9D, 0xA5, 0xAB, 0xB2, 0xB9, 0xC1, 0xC9, 0xD2, 0xD9,
0xDE, 0xE3, 0xE8, 0xED, 0xF5]

c06738_lookups = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
c06740_chooser = 0
dword_C06748 = 0

def calc_crit():
    return 99 * sub_5D191A() / 65535 + 1

def sub_5D191A():
    return sub_5C8BF2()

def sub_5C8BF2():
    v2 = sub_5C8BA1()
    v0 = dword_C06748 + 1 and 7
    if (v0):
        sub_5C8B80()
    return v2 or (sub_5C8BA1() << 8)

def sub_5C8BA1():
    return rn_table[c06740_chooser[c06738_lookups]+1]

def sub_5C8B80():
    result = dword_C06738 + 1 + 1
    c06738_lookups and 7
    return result

calc_crit()
print "c06738_lookups: %r" % c06738_lookups
```

I want `index` to be the position number of the list `lookups`. So I want to increment the index, so that it looks at position 1 (which is the value `4` in the list.)

I want to increment index so that I can do an operation on the 2nd value in the list (I obviously don't want this hardcoded, as I want to cycle through the positions at will).

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just assign to `index` then? `index += 1`.

Comment: why would you want to do this instead of just using standard ways of working with lists in python?

Comment: Also, your Lua code does something completely different from the C code.

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Then if I want to take the position 1 in the list and increment that value (so it will take '4' and increment by 1 and store it back to the list)?

Comment: @Stuart I've only been learning Python for 1 day, so I'm not sure what the standard ways are.

Comment: What's the expected output? This means nothing to me as-is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you sure it does something completely different? I think it is the same (same results when I run the entire script)

Comment: @Veedrac I'm new to programming and the script isn't finished yet. I want to do exactly as the pseudocode is doing. It is a kind of look up table to the 255 values in 'rn' list.

Comment: It's not at all clear what your pseudocode is supposed to do - what is offset2? Also, I suspect there will be better ways of doing this than keeping a look up table, if you can explain more broadly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Stuart I'm trying to do something like this: http://pastie.org/8344190

It has to be a lookup table because I'm trying to reverse engineer something using Python :)

Comment: What version of Lua are you running? `memory.readbyte` is not a standard Lua function, neither in [Lua5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/#index) nor in [Lua 5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/contents.html#index).

Comment: In the full code your way of mixing up lists and integers is not going to work... I guess you are trying to translate pointers from C. I suggest googling some practice exercises to get used to the very different way Python lists work first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you want to do is this:

```
lookups = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
index = 0
def increment_next_value():
    global lookups, index
    lookups[index] += 1
    index += 1
```

This function first adds one to the first value in `lookups` (2 becomes 3) then to the second value (4 becomes 5) and so on.

This is a very un-pythonic way of translating the code and global variables are best avoided by using classes and objects. In general you're likely to have a lot of difficulty porting from C to Python on a one-function-at-a-time basis, and it would be better if you can understand what the C code does and rewrite it properly in Python using a style that is suited to the language.

Comment: Don't do this. At least use a class.

Comment: @Marcin One step at a time - the OP needs to understand lists first.  but see my edits.